# Error reactotron createStore is not function

Tags: react-native, reactotron

I have a sample code use this packages:

- reactotron-react-native
- reactotron-redux
- reactotron-redux-saga

file index.js

```
...
import "./ReactotronConfig";
...
const createAppropriateStore = __DEV__ ? console.tron.createStore : createStore;
const store = createAppropriateStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

file ReactotronConfig.js

```
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";
if (__DEV__) {
  const tron = Reactotron.configure({ host: "192.168.1.17" })
    .useReactNative()
    .connect();

  tron.clear();

  console.tron = tron;
}
```

Result show this bug

[image: bug]

But if I replace `console.tron.createStore` to `createStore` it will work again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
import "./ReactotronConfig";
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native'
...
const createAppropriateStore = !__DEV__ ? console.tron.createStore : Reactotron.createStore;
const store = createAppropriateStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

Comment: Because `__DEV__ = true` not false, so i think `console.tron.createStore` never work

Comment: @HaiTruong IT Then change the condition to falsehoods like my corrected answer.